# ElasticSearch Query: Get `key` from each record within ElasticSearch and return a collection of unique values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get `categories` from each record within ElasticSearch and return a collection of unique categories.

Given I have a collection of books

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

# Response

{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_source": {
          "title" : "Amazing Book",
          "categories": [
            {
                "id" : "123",
                "name" : "Comedy"
            },
            {
                "id" : "456",
                "name" : "Action"
            }
          ],
        }
      },
      {
        "_source": {
          "title" : "Other Amazing Book",
          "categories": [
            {
                "id" : "456",
                "name" : "Action"
            },
            {
                "id" : "987",
                "name" : "Romance"
            }
          ],
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What query would produce this output?

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
        "id" : "123",
        "name" : "Comedy"
    },
    {
        "id" : "456",
        "name" : "Action"
    },
    {
        "id" : "987",
        "name" : "Romance"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is related to the **aggregrations** feature.

I achieved to produce a suitable output, but you must change your mapping like this :

```
POST test/book/_mapping
{
"properties": {
    "title":{
      "type": "string"
    },
    "categories":{
      "type": "nested" 
    }
  }
}
```

Then, if you index the documents :

```
PUT test/book/1
{
  "title" : "Amazing Book",
  "categories": [
    {
        "id" : "123",
        "name" : "Comedy"
    },
    {
        "id" : "456",
        "name" : "Action"
    }
  ]
}

PUT test/book/2
{
  "title" : "Other Amazing Book",
  "categories": [
    {
        "id" : "456",
        "name" : "Action"
    },
    {
        "id" : "987",
        "name" : "Romance"
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, the following search request :

```
GET test/book/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "categories"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "categories.id"
          }
          , 
          "aggs": {
            "name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "categories.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

produces this output (I extracted the relevant part) :

```
"aggregations": {
      "categories": {
         "doc_count": 4,
         "id": {
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "456",
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "name": {
                     "buckets": [
                        {
                           "key": "action",
                           "doc_count": 2
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "123",
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "name": {
                     "buckets": [
                        {
                           "key": "comedy",
                           "doc_count": 1
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "987",
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "name": {
                     "buckets": [
                        {
                           "key": "romance",
                           "doc_count": 1
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
```

The reason you have to change the mapping is that, using the default mapping, the JSON document is flattened into a simple key-value format, something like :

```
{
  "title": "Amazing book",
  "categories.id": [123 , 456],
  "categories.name": [comedy, action],
}
```

In this case, **you lose the association between "123" and "Comedy"**, and an equivalent aggregations (just remove the "nested" agg) will output :

```
"aggregations": {
      "categories": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "456",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "name": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "action",
                        "doc_count": 2
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "comedy",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "romance",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "123",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "name": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "action",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "comedy",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "987",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "name": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "action",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "romance",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```